# Почему после ввода строки, содержащей "\n" на выходе получаю "\\n"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

При написании программы вылезла ошибка. Я установил, где она находится. Она заключается в этом коде:

```py
line = input()  #Ввожу b\nc
print(line) # Получаю b\\nc
```

[image: фото кода, который я пробовал сделать]

Никак не могу понять, почему так происходит и что с этим делать.
Как мне сделать так, чтобы 'line' у меня ссылалась на "b\nc"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

встроенная функция [input()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) воспринимает символ перевода строки `\n` как конец ввода. Соответственно ввести несколько строк одним вызовом `input()` не получится.

Но это легко обойти:

```
In [39]: line = input()
b\nc\nd

In [40]: print(line)
b\nc\nd

In [41]: line = line.replace('\\n', '\n')

In [42]: print(line)
b
c
d
```

Comment: Брррррррррррррррр.. А как теперь ввести просто `\n` в строке, а не символ перехода на новую строку? Хочется городить экранирование, так делай по-человечески. а не так.

Comment: @Qwertiy, можете воспринимать это как "костыль")